# RubyonRails routes redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I guess I am not an expert while we talk about Rails routings.

I have two controllers. One for the web actions and another for the api actions. Web controller is named 'Story' and Api controller also named 'Story' but is at other location 'api/v1/Story'.

There is a method called 'download_story' in web story controller.  Routing for both of the controllers are(config.rb):

```
// Web controller routing
get '/stories/download-story/:id', to: 'stories#download_story', as: :download_stroy

// Api controller routing
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  namespace :v1 do
    get '/download/:id', to: 'stories#download_story', as: :download_story
  end
end
```

Question is "How to call the web controller action(download_story) from api controller along with the params?"

What I have tried is:

```
// Api controller routing
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  namespace :v1 do
    get '/download/:id', to: redirect('/stories/download_story/%{id}')
  end
end
```

Which is redirecting to '/stories/download_story' of Web controller. But I send a request to:

```
'curl 'localhost:3000/api/v1/download/1'
```

It sends me only plain response. Response is :

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000/stories/download_story/:id">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Nothing after that. It is not really redirected.

Comment: you can redirect `redirect_to download_story_path(params)`

Comment: also, I think you have a typo `download_stroy` instead of `download_story`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale, Already tried this. Did not work. Two reasons : 
-> params would not be acceptable.
-> Should'nt it be redirect instead of redirect_to?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. Should be done as:

```
get '/download/:id', to: '/story#download_story
```

This will redirect to the download action of the story controller.